# SQL - Complex Data Migration from Old Structure to New Structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Alright, so here is the interesting problem...

I want to move data from **OldApplicationLogs** table to two tables:

1. UserSessionLogs
2. ApplicationLogs

This is the structure of the OldApplicationLogs:

```
ID INT-PK
UserID INT-FK
PropertyID INT-FK
Controller VARCHAR
Action VARCHAR
EntityType VARCHAR
EntityKey VARCHAR
AbsoluteURL VARCHAR
IPAddress VARCHAR
...
```

And these are the new structures I'm trying to move it into:

**UserSessionLogs**

```
ID INT-PK
UserID INT-FK
PropertyID INT-FK
IPAddress INT-FK
...
```

**ApplicationLogs**

```
ID INT-PK
UserSessionLogID INT-FK
EntityID INT-FK
EntityKey INT
Controller VARCHAR
Action VARCHAR
RelativeURL VARCHAR
Created VARCHAR
...
```

Now the approach I have in mind is:

1. Treat all the unique UserID, PropertyID, IPAddress as one row of
   UserSessionLogs.
2. Move data from old app log structure to the new one.

Here goes the SQL statements I began to write...

**SQL Codes, recommended for your eyes**:
http://kendtimothy.com/static/logs_so_30-12-2015.pdf

Otherwise, this is the SQL codes:

1. Map past data of each user occurrence as one user session.

   ```
   SELECT 
       ID, PropertyID, UserID, IPAddress INTO UserSessionLogs 
   FROM
       OldApplicationLogs
   GROUP BY 
       PropertyID, UserID, IPAddress
   ```

Question 1: Loop through the results and insert into the UserSessionLogs.

```
INSERT INTO UserSessionLogs (PropertyID, IPAddress, UserID, StartDate)
VALUES (UserSessionLogs.PropertyID, UserSessionLogs.IPAddress, UserSessionLogs.UserID)
```

2. Map past data of all app logs to the new structure.

   ```
   SELECT * 
   INTO AppLogs 
   FROM OldApplicationLogs
   ```

Question 2: Again, I need to loop through the results and insert into `ApplicationLogs`.

```
INSERT INTO ApplicationLogs (UserSessionLogID, [Action], Controller, Operation, Created, EntityID, EntityKey, RelativeURL)
VALUES (
```

Question 3: How can I get the relevant `UserID` where the `PropertyID`, `UserID` and `IPAddress` combination matches?

```
UserSessions.ID,
AppLogs.Action,
AppLogs.Controller,
AppLogs.Operation,
AppLogs.LoggedDate
```

Get the `EntityID` which has the same table name.

```
(SELECT TableName 
 FROM Entities 
 WHERE AppLogs.EntityType = Entities.TableName),
```

Cast the previously `VARCHAR` EntityKey to `INT`? EntityKey. Leave NULL as it is.

```
CAST(AppLogs.EntityKey AS INT),
```

Convert absolute URL (from past structure) to relative URL.

Question 4 / Suggestion: Any suggestion of a better way to do this is super welcomed :)

```
REPLACE(AppLogs.AbsoluteURL, 'www.myapp.com/', '')
)
```

I'll really appreciate the help/suggestion in this, cheers :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @StanShaw The question is actually marked as a comment in the SQL codes. I marked it with -- Question 1, -- Question 2, etc. Hope it's not too much trouble. Basically, how to achieve looping through query results and getting ID which matches Question 3.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to loop through anything, but you should write inserts based upon joins to preserve your original associations.  I don't have time to answer now, but will try to help edit your post for clarity.

Comment: Thank you! Your edit certainly breaks the question much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No loops are necessary here.  SQL is best when working with sets of data.

Without the full DDL for the tables this may be somewhat off.

```
INSERT INTO [UserSessionLogs]([PropertyID], [IPAddress], [UserID])
SELECT [PropertyID], [UserID], [IPAddress]
FROM [OldApplicationLogs]
GROUP BY [PropertyID], [UserID], [IPAddress];

INSERT INTO [ApplicationLogs]([UserSessionLogID], [Action], [Controller], [Operation], [Created], [EntityID], [EntityKey], [RelativeURL])
SELECT 
    B.[ID],
    A.[Action], 
    A.[Controller],
    A.[Operation],
    A.[LoggedDate],
    C.[TableName],
    CAST(A.[EntityKey] AS INT),
    REPLACE(A.[AbsoluteURL],'www.myapp.com/','')
FROM [OldApplicationLogs] A
INNER JOIN [UserSessionLogs] B
ON      A.[UserID] = B.[UserID]
LEFT JOIN [Entities] C
ON      A.[EntityType] = C.[TableName]
```

The `C.[TableName]` seems like it would be a VARCHAR instead of an ID per your definition of `ApplicationLogs`.  Perhaps you meant to use `EntityID` instead of `TableName`?

Comment: Yes, I wanted C.[ID] instead of C.[TableName].This works out too great, requiring only minor adjustments. You have been a great help mate. Thank you so much! :)